# comparar en un switch los rangos de horas y sumarlos

Tags: php

Hola Chicos tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo en un array los registros de los horarios de las asistencias
que son las siguientes:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "11:13:09"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "13:06:12"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "13:28:05"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "09:59:59"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "13:14:27"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "13:34:58"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "14:32:20"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "14:33:38"
  ...
```

como puedo sumarlos y acumularlos con su respectivo horario en el siguiente switch:

```php
switch ($horas) {
            
            case ($$horas >= '08:00:00') && ($$horas <= '09:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($$horas >= '09:00:00') && ($$horas <= '10:00:00'):
                
                
                break;
            case ($$horas >= '10:00:00') && ($$horas <= '11:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($$horas >= '11:00:00') && ($$horas <= '12:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '12:00:00') && ($horas <= '13:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '13:00:00') && ($horas <= '14:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '14:00:00') && ($horas <= '15:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '15:00:00') && ($horas <= '16:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '16:00:00') && ($horas <= '17:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '17:00:00') && ($horas <= '18:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '18:00:00') && ($horas<= '19:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas>= '19:00:00') && ($horas<= '20:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas>= '20:00:00') && ($horas <= '21:00:00'):
                
                break;
            case ($horas >= '21:00:00:') && ($horas <= '22:00:00'):
                
                break;
        }
```

Comment: sumar que? o de que forma?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: usando un contador .... `$count++;`

Comment: en el array que les mostré existen horas del mismo rango ejemplo: 13:28:05 , 13:14:27, 13:05:05  como hago para que me las cuente en el switch  y que me de el resultado de 3 y asi con las otros horarios no se si me entienda

Comment: no te estoy entendiendo ... cuando dices contar como te imaginas que las cuenta?

Comment: que esperas que hagas si tubieras estas tres horas: 13:28:05 , 13:14:27, 13:05:05???

Comment: lo que espero es que me muestre que en el caso : case ($horas >= '13:00:00') && ($horas <= '14:00:00'): un resultado de 3 ,                                               ya que entra en ese rango

Comment: y si hay existiece una hora mas como:  13:28:05 , 13:14:27, 13:05:05, 15:05:05 en cual se supone que debe entrar?

Comment: estos horarios 13:28:05 , 13:14:27, 13:05:05 entra en el caso de: case ($horacoach >= '13:00:00') && ($horacoach <= '14:00:00'): ya que el caso funciona de un rango de 13:00:00 a 13:59:59. y el horario de 15:05:05 entrara en el caso de : case ($horacoach >= '15:00:00') && ($horacoach <= '16:00:00'): por que es de 15:00:00 a 15:59:59

Comment: y el resultado de contar las horas cuanto deberia de ser???

Comment: pues en cada case pondría un variable que me los acumule y el resultado seria ejemplo si existen estos horarios 13:28:05 , 13:14:27, 13:34:58 , 13:54:30 en el rango de  ($horacoach >= '13:00:00') && ($horacoach <= '14:00:00'): el resultado seria 4

Comment: que pasa si tienes un 15:05:05 colado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario el `switch`, basta un arreglo cuyo índice sea la hora inicial, asumiendo rangos de una hora por cada entrada del horario. Entonces te limitas  a insertar elementos para cada horario con base en la hora, es decir, descartando minutos y segundos. El resto es sólo darle un formato adecuado al arreglo resultante, por ejemplo con `printf()`:

```
for( $i=8; $i<=21; $horario[$i++]=[] ); // Iniciar arreglo

foreach( ['11:13:09','13:06:12','13:28:05','09:59:59','13:14:27','13:34:58','14:32:20','14:33:38'] as $h ){
  $i = explode(':',$h);
  $horario[intval(array_shift($i))][] = $h; // Insertar elemento en horario
}

foreach( $horario as $i => $h )
  printf( "%2d:00:00 - %2d:00:00 => %d [%s]\n"
         , $i
         , $i+1
         , count($h)
         , implode(',',$h)
         );
```

Resultado:

```
 8:00:00 -  9:00:00 => 0 []
 9:00:00 - 10:00:00 => 1 [09:59:59]
10:00:00 - 11:00:00 => 0 []
11:00:00 - 12:00:00 => 1 [11:13:09]
12:00:00 - 13:00:00 => 0 []
13:00:00 - 14:00:00 => 4 [13:06:12,13:28:05,13:14:27,13:34:58]
14:00:00 - 15:00:00 => 2 [14:32:20,14:33:38]
15:00:00 - 16:00:00 => 0 []
16:00:00 - 17:00:00 => 0 []
17:00:00 - 18:00:00 => 0 []
18:00:00 - 19:00:00 => 0 []
19:00:00 - 20:00:00 => 0 []
20:00:00 - 21:00:00 => 0 []
21:00:00 - 22:00:00 => 0 []
```